# How to enable Mercurial topics (is it a "live" feature yet)?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-topics

Following the tutorial at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/tutorials/topic-tutorial.html I added the following to my `mercurial.ini` file:

```
[extensions]
  ...
evolve =

[experimental]
evolution = all
```

Yet when I go to the command line and try it out:

```
# hg topic
hg: unknown command 'topic'
(did you mean pick?)

# hg topics
hg: unknown command 'topics'
(use 'hg help' for a list of commands)
```

That's all I get.

(`hg evolve` does work, however.)

I've searched but can't find any other documentation on either how to enable it, or if maybe it just isn't in the regular releases yet. But from other posts here & elsewhere, it does seem that people are using it. Although it is not listed in https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UsingExtensions.

What do I need to do to enable it?

---

My version of hg is the latest:

```
# hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.6.1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial is incorrect (out of date?)

You have to add the following to the Mercurial configuration file:

```
[extensions]
evolve =
topic =
```

I eventually spotted this at https://heptapod.net/pages/quick-start-guide.html.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to provide paths to make it work on my system:

```
[extensions]
evolve = C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\hgext3rd\evolve
topic = C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\hgext3rd\topic
```

Comment: I've never had to specify a path like that for HG. Is there anything unusual or customized about your HG installation?